# ESENT Out of table cursors

Tags: extensible-storage-engine

Our Windows application uses Extensible Storage Engine (ESENT). After a while of reading and writing to ESENT, this error occurs:

```
#define JET_errOutOfCursors                 -1013 /* Out of table cursors */
```

I'm not familiar with ESENT, and can't seem to find a good description of this error on MSDN. What does it mean? Is there any way I can see how many table cursors are available at a given time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, a "cursor" in the context of ESE is a separate state/view of a table within an ESE session.

You can get and set a system parameter, "JET_paramMaxCursors" informing ESE of how many concurrent ESE cursors you can have open and active under any one ESE session.  You must set this parameter prior to issuing your JetInit call.

It's rather odd how the ESE documentation uses JET_TABLEID and "cursor" interchangeably without a deep discussion as to the differences, if any, between the two.